# What is the elastic search query for nested aggregation to return buckets of count values?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have data of individual customers in Elastic Search, whose likings of Food_Item are stored as shown below. A customer likes many "Food_Items". So its a list. I have many customers also.

I have data in the following format:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "customerName":"John",
   "likings":[
        {
           "Food_Item": "Pizza",
           "OnAScaleOfTen": 9
        },
        {
           "Food_Item": "Chinese",
           "OnAScaleOfTen": 10
        }
   ]
},

{
   "id": 2,
   "customerName":"Mary",
   "likings":[
        {
           "Food_Item": "Burger",
           "OnAScaleOfTen": 10
        },
        {
           "Food_Item": "Chinese",
           "OnAScaleOfTen": 6
        }
   ]
}
```

Now if i want to bucket list the unique "Food_Items" and their corresponding count something like this in the **AGGR** result:

```
"Liking_Status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Chinese",
                    "Liking Count": {
                        "value": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Pizza",
                    "Liking Count": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Burger",
                    "Liking Count": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                }]}
```

My mapping for the index is:

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "customerName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "likings": {
        "type":"nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "Food_Item": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "OnAScaleOfTen": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the Elastic Search Query. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the below answer?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Gibbs. Can u please tell me how do I exactly get it in this format:

 {
                    "key": "Burger",
                    "Liking Count": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                }

Comment: Does it work for you? If so could u approve it else tell us what's missing

Comment: Actually I am disconnected from the dev set up now. I will be able to connect tomorrow and check.

Comment: Hi Gibbs, i was able to connect to the dev machine just now. Its saying "[nested] nested path [likings] is not nested" error.

Comment: Your question says it's nested. But that's not the case. Can you add mapping by doing GET http://host:port/indexName/_mapping

Comment: @Gibbs. I have updated the mapping file. Your query is working. But please help me to get the output in the format  { "key": "Burger", "Liking Count": { "value": 1 } }  and not as "doc_count."  Because a plugin requires data in this format.

Comment: @Gibbs any updates?

Comment: I will update it today. Mostly it's not possible to transform. But I will check

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": { //aggregating on nested field
      "nested": {
        "path": "likings"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "liking_count": {//term aggregation on the obj
          "terms": {
            "field": "likings.Food_Item.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping:

I just mentioned that `likings` as nested. Apart from others are default. In this case, Food_Item is a text. Terms aggs works on keywords. So used keyword version of it from the index.

Output:

```
"aggregations": {
        "buckets": {
            "doc_count": 4,
            "liking_count": { //You can name what you want here
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "Chinese",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Burger",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Pizza",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```